# How to return a constant or a text string in PHP -- is eval() the way to go

Tags: php, eval

I have a row in a mysql table whose column contains:

```
This is a test.
```

I have another row in the same mysql table whose same column contains:

```
K_IM_A_CONSTANT
```

Earlier on in the PHP script, this line of code exists:

```
define(K_IM_A_CONSTANT, 'This is a constant.');
```

How can I echo the contents of the column whereby, the returned value would either be "This is a test." or "This is a constant.",  depending on the row selected?

Is eval() the way to do it? If so, how might the eval() syntax look? I have been getting too many errors trying to get eval() to work.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: See my add-on that starts with [CONTINUED]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [`constant`](http://php.net/constant) function:

```
if(defined($row['column_name']))
{
    echo constant($row['column_name']);
}
```

Comment: Well for clarification, my mysql query select result is $row['the_column']....so I will try your constant($row['the_column']) solution.

Comment: It works fine when the column contained the constant but when the column contained the text string I got the following error -- Couldn't find constant This is a test.

Comment: @Dr. Dot, of course you will since the text passed to `constant` is not a constant.

Comment: Ah ha, that looks like it might work --thanks Tim...I'll test and comment back

Comment: But Kevin...I am merely disproving that constant($row['the_column']) was not the solution. Thanks for the critique ;)

Comment: Thanks Tim, that was the answer. Sometimes I get too close to a solution that I lose sight of possible alternatives. Needed to step back...but you solved it for me quite nicely. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

So given a piece of text, you want to find the name of a constant whose value matches the piece of text? This seems like a hideous abuse of "constants" to me, but, you'd want to use `get_defined_constants()`:

```
function find_constant_name($text) {
    $constants = get_defined_constants();
    foreach($constants as $const => $val) {
        if ($val == 'Your specified text') {
             return($const);
        }
    }
}

find_constant_name('This is a test.');
```

Comment: Well, I just want to return the contents of the column. If the column contents is a constant, I want its defined value, I just want the value of the column.